# How to Define a Double Environment?

Tags: environments

For example, I wanna short the environment

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
...
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

to
`\begin{eqt} ... \end{eqt}`
. But it report errors when I add the following preamble

```
\newenvironment{eqt}{\begin{equation}\begin{split}}
    {\end{split}\end{equation}}
```

Can anyone show me the correct code or point out the err?